# Dealing with schema changes in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, view, schema

I use MongoDB in one of my Java projects. After a DB schema change, I found myself modifying existing code at a lot of places to perform the change from e.g.:

```
Object result = collection.findOne();
```

to

```
Object result = collection.findOne().get("ThisField").get("ThatField");
```

Now, things are relatively simple in the `findOne()` case, but they get more complex when `find()` and the associated cursors come to play.

In most cases, it would have been far easier if I could modify the *query*, rather than its result. I have already experimented with [retrieving specfic fields only](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields), but as far as I can tell, that only masks the rest of the fields - it does not change the structure of the object.

- Is it possible to specify a query so that the objects that form the values of a specific field are "promoted" to a top-level object, thus removing the `.get("this").get("that")` calls?
- As a further step, does MongoDB support any equivalent to the [views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29), as seen in conventional databases? Something that might allow existing code to continue working in case of a schema change?

Comment: Have you considered updating the collection such that ThisField values are copied to the ThatField attribute? Is there a backwards compatibility reason to keep the old attribute around under its original name?

Comment: @jtoberson: storing and maintaining duplicate fields is a nightmare - I'd have to make sure that all DB updates would do The Right Thing, namely updating both fields, rather than just one of them. Not to mention the possibility of a conflict between the old and new schema...

Comment: @jtoberson: I have a lot of code that I did not write and that I have not delved into yet. Keeping the schema compatible, would allow me the time to refactor it correctly, rather than having to perform a lot of patchwork *now*. Failing that, modifying the queries is easier than having to find where their results pop up in the code and modifying the code there...

Comment: Of course you shouldn't keep both. Actually I was going to suggest that you drop the old field completely. To drop the old field, isn't it as simple as searching for all usages of "ThisField" and replacing them with "ThatField"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that MongoDB does not currently have any server-side equivalent of the relational database views. The [MongoDB Map/Reduce support](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) is apparently suitable only for batch operations, which makes it useless for an online database with real-time updates.

As a workaround, I turned to a client-side solution. I took advantage of the fact that the Java driver is open source and thus I could easily work out how it is structured.

More specifically, I was able to extend and [replace](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6.5/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#setDBDecoderFactory%28com.mongodb.DBDecoderFactory%29) the default BSON decoder for the collections of interest and transparently relocate the fields that had moved.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second question is probably a **Map/Reduce** function.  However, there are some considerations:

- Map/Reduce is usually to do aggregate calculations, but can be used as a View in the sense that it will go through every object in the collection and will generate an output collection where your documents are aggregated (counts, sums, etc.) or are transformed (*for each document, if ThisField is present return ThisField, otherwise return ThatField*)
- It runs on the server so you can schedule jobs to generate your collections (representing the concept of a View); however, you need to consider that MapReduce is not good for online queries.  It is intended to do background jobs to transform data very efficiently, but not to run queries (unless you only have a small collection).

So I would add that if you want to 'migrate' your schema, you could run a map/reduce and save it as a new permanent collection with the new schema.  All you need to do to continue programming against the new schema is to use the new collection.